# Update Dictionary Values with Key

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults, swift4

this is my dictionary value

```
var dict: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
dict = pref.object(forKey: KEY_USER_LOGIN_INFO) as! NSDictionary
print(dict as Any)

{
    cityId = 1;
    cityName = Dammam;
    countryId = 1;
    mobile = 123;
    name = "My name";
}
```

now i have to update cityid = "2", mobile = "456", name = "othername"
 and create same as above Dictionary with updated values.
 help me with this.

Comment: So what is the issue, I mean what we help you to do this?

Comment: [`updateValue(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1539001-updatevalue), or you can use [subscript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2885650-subscript) to assign a new value to a key as well – the documentation is your friend, don't be shy to use it.

Comment: updateValue(_:forkey:) worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code as below

```
 var dict = pref.object(forKey: KEY_USER_LOGIN_INFO) as! Dictionary<String,Any>
dict["cityid"] = "2"
dict["mobile"] = "456"
dic["name"] =  "other name"
```

you are forcefully unwraping the dictionary it is not recommended ..

Answer (score 1):

You can not update value in `NSDictionary`, so you have to use `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
var dict: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
dict = (pref.object(forKey: KEY_USER_LOGIN_INFO) as! NSDictionary).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary
dict["cityId"] = 2
dict["mobile"] = 456
dict["name"] = "othername"
print(dict)
```